# use two auth methods with Guzzle

Tags: php, authentication, guzzle, ntlm, digest

I need to send a POST request to an API. When using curl on the console it only works when I set --ntlm AND --digest at the same time, I am not completely sure why. (The API is really weird in general).

Now I want to send the same request with guzzle, but the auth parameter in the options array only allows one method to be specified.

Can I somehow overwrite this, e.g. by injecting CURL_OPTs ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the problem. Curl implies --negotiate if you set two auth-flags (like --ntlm, --digest). This was what I really needed.

You can do this with guzzle by setting the curl parameter:

```
$guzzle_params = [
    'curl' => [CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH =>  6, 
               CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'user:pass'
    ]
];
```

Note: this of course only works with the curl handler in guzzle.